# how can I add a vector to a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can I add a vector to a matrix in Matlab, in a manner that the i's index of the vector would be added to all the members in the i's row?

for example:

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6;
     6 7 8]
v = [1;
     2;
     3]
```

the required result is:

```
[2 3 4;
 6 7 8;
 9 10 11]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean add a vector to a particular row of a matrix??

Comment: Do you mean to 1)add a nx1 array to then end of a nxm matrix, enlarging the matrix 2) insert such an array into the middle of a matrix, enlarging the matrix 3) overwrite that array, keeping the same size matrix 4) are you able to preallocate a matrix of zeros and thus do 3) anyway (it would be faster than augmenting the matrix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to `bsxfun` is to use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) and repeat the column vector `v` as many times as `A` has columns:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 6 7 8];
v = [1; 2; 3]

A = A + repmat(v,1,3);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
B=bsxfun(@plus,A,v);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun:

```
A + v(:,[1 1 1]);
```

Comment: Honestly, this was my favorite answer.  I'm a MATLAB/Octave beginner and the use of this (or a version using ones()) has made my life much easier.  Thanks.