# How to perform this kind of matrix division in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

This problem is probably less to do with Matlab and more to do with matrix algebra (which I mostly forget from my college courses). Say I have a `m x n` matrix `X` and a `m x 1` matrix `B`. How would I divide the `X` by `B` such that all the elements of the `i`th row of X are piecewise divided by the `i`th row of B, resulting in another `m x n` matrix `Y`?

E.g.

```
X = [2 4 8; 3 9 27; 4 16 64]
B = [2; 3; 4]

X ? B = [2/2 4/2 8/2; 3/3 9/3 27/3; 4/4 16/4 64/4]
ans   = 
           1     2     4
           1     3     9
           1     4    16
```

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066084/how-can-i-add-a-vector-to-a-matrix-in-matlab/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Better not use `repmat` - it is slow and allocates additional memory for the workspace. You can use `bsxfun`, which is an inbuilt function, so it is faster and avoids the extra workspace:

```
X = [2 4 8; 3 9 27; 4 16 64]
B = [2; 3; 4]
bsxfun(@rdivide, X, B)

ans =

 1     2     4
 1     3     9
 1     4    16
```

Answer (score 1):

Junuxx's comment pointed me in the right direction. The solution I used to get what I wanted is:

```
B_prime = repmat(B,1,3)

X ./ B_prime

ans =

 1     2     4
 1     3     9
 1     4    16
```

I'd still like to know what this kind of operation is called (if it even has a formal name).

Answer (score 0):

X is `m x n` and B is `m x 1`

`size(X,2)` gives the value of n i.e. number of columns

So, you need to do:

```
X./repmat(B,1,size(X,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

X = [2 4 8; 3 9 27; 4 16 64]

B = [2; 3; 4]

Result= X./**B(:,ones(1,3))** %is faster then repmat

Result =

```
 1     2     4
 1     3     9
 1     4    16
```